# IBM MobileFirst: User device ID mapping without security realm

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

**The objective is :**  we have to connect to OAUTH based web service to authenticate a user. Once the OAUTH responds back with success, we have to create a user id mapping initiated.

**What I'm able to complete is:** create security test & realm and added it to an adapter. With this when i tried to invoke a test HTTP/XML service from MobileFirst, I'm able to see the device user mapping in the console.

**Question is:** Is it mandatory to have security test/realm to have this mapping tone initiated or can we create a UserIdentity object ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user identity object without a security-test but you must use some realm!
The realm name is a mandatory property for the WL.Server.setActiveUser(Realm name, UserIdentity object) API and also for the WL.Client.getLoginName(Realm name) API.

Comment: Thanks Shmulik - Checked and looks like thats the response.

Comment: In my adapter there is a procedure without any test, but when the user invokes it, I call a external service from the adapter and I receive say a valid response. Now based on this response I would want to set the setActiveUser("a-valid-realm-declared-in-authconfig.xml",{'userId':'somevalue'}), doing this I'm unable to achieve the above problem statement. Can you please help.